# Who can use a Ring of adept maneuvers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm here to ask your assistance to locate an official ruling or errata about an item.

Last time our Group played we got among the enemy's belongings a **Ring of adept maneuvers**. According to our DM's description it needs two ki points to provide its benefits, which include a bonus to Combat Maneuvers, which would be fantastic for our party's **brawler**. During the subsequent conversation we said we'll look for a friendly monk to charge the ring and then give it to the brawler, and our DM said that he's not sure it works like that.

As far as I know, the wearer needs to have a ki pool in order to charge the ring, but after reading the description, I believe it can later be passed onto someone else who could receive the bonuses without the ring losing its charges, while my DM says that's not the case.

He said too that he'll allow us to use the ring in that manner only if we can find an official ruling allowing this use of the charged ring by a non-ki pool user.

So the question is this: **According to RAW, can a Ring of Adept Maneuvers be charged by a character with a ki pool and then be given to a character without a ki pool to use? Would this second character receive its benefits?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's no official clarification one way of the other, and it depends on the DM's interpretation, so the answers is: it depends on your DM's ruling**

The text of the ring's description is ambiguous enough that both the answers provided by **KRyan** and **DuckTapeAl** can be considered correct if you're inclined to accept their very valid reasoning. Regrettably I cannot mark one of their answers as the accepted answer over the other one because both me and my DM consider both answers equally valid, but thank you for expressing both sides of the argument so clearly.

Answer (score 10):

You are correct, but I highly doubt you’ll find an official ruling on the matter. Google cannot find one. And honestly, I suspect the interaction you’re planning on here was unintentional.

But as far as the rules as written, they’re pretty clear:

> The ring allows a wearer with a ki pool to store up to 2 ki points in the ring as a swift action. **These points remain in the ring until used.**

There are no ifs, ands, or buts about this. Nothing about taking off the ring or giving it to someone else is said to take the points out. For that matter, nothing about the points going away when the monk refreshes his *ki* points, which I would have expected even if it was being used by a monk.

Comment: A monk's "ki pool is replenished each morning after 8 hours of rest or meditation," so the real issue is convincing a friendly monk that he can do without that *ki* for today, which, honestly, shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: @HeyICanChan True, but... no, I give up. I have no idea what Paizo was going for here. The idea that charging the ring has effectively no cost whatsoever (and it can in fact be used as an extra 2 points above your usual in an emergency) just doesn’t seem... like something that would be a feature without *saying* that explicitly.

Comment: Spend two ki on a day when you don't need it, have two extra ki available in an emergency, gain small buffs by keeping the ki in storage.  It's straightforward enough.  Reminds me of the "Ready..." feats for the Mesmerist.  Store a trick in an ally (or yourself), gain a buff from the feats until you activate and use up the trick, which also forfeits the buffs.  They work nearly identically.

Comment: The alternative — that the monk's *ki* pool is reduced by 1 or 2 until the points are used from the *ring* — is far worse, since breaking or losing the *ring* means the monk's *ki* pool is permanently depleted. I don't think any monk would dare risk that. The item becomes a ivory tower design trap.

Answer (score 6):

### The *ki* points remain, but you have to have *ki* to get benefits from them.

I'm pretty sure this is the interpretation that you DM is considering.  The text of the ring is abundantly clear that the *ki* points stay around until they are used, no matter who is currently using the ring.  However:

> The ring allows a **wearer with a ki pool** to store up to 2 ki points in the ring as a swift action. The **wearer** can use the ki points normally, but gains the following benefits when ki points are stored in the ring.

My interpretation of this text is that "wearer" is referring to the aforementioned "wearer with a *ki* pool".  Thus, a Monk could invest some *ki* into the ring and use it later, or even give that ring to another Monk, but a wearer who didn't have a *ki* pool can't use the item.  It still has the points stored, they're just currently inaccessible.

As an aside, this means that a Monk could store a huge amount of *ki* if they had enough rings, since they can store 2 *ki* in each ring they have.